# Redirect with current domain at the end - Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

For my WordPress website, I use the plugin **Wp domain checker**. You can check if a domain is available and proceed with a redirect. The problem is that I want it to redirect to a special redirect depending on the page where the domain checker is embedded in. For example, if it is embeded in: `test.com/page1` and the redirect would be `test.com/succes` I want it to redirect to `test.com/succes-https://test.com/page1`

With the plugin that I am using, you can add `{domain}` at the end to redirect to a special URL with the chosen domain at the end. I want this functionality, but then with the current URL instead of the chosen domain. I know that this works via an input text field, with the `name="domain"`

Do I need to do this with **PHP**, or should I use the following **JavaScript function**, but how?

```js
document.write(window.location.href)
```

And do I need to insert the code into the plugin **PHP** code, or in the current **WordPress page**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that there is a very simple way of doing this. Because it uses a href link you can simply turn the href link into this `href='redirect'` and then it would go to `http://example.com/page1/redirect`. This is approach 1, but you can also use another approach, with PHP.

The second approach is to use `href='$current_url redirect'` and then this should be the PHP function: `$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));`

It grabs the current WP page, which you can then use in the href. Then the text with a space behind the function is the redirect, so it will redirect to the same page as approach 1.